# python fnmatch.fnmatch("[seq]") escape not working

Tags: python, escaping, fnmatch

According to the https://bugs.python.org/issue13929, "[seq]" should be escaped by the backslash. However, when i run the same code, i have different result like bellow

[image]

I need to detect the string contains the "[" and "]". So, my solution is to change "[seq]" to the "{seq}" on both string and pattern like bellow.

```
string = string.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")
pattern = pattern.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")
fnmatch.fnmatch(string, pattern)
```

Could there be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fnmatch` does not support escaping with backslashes. Instead, you should enclose special characters in square brackets. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html):

> For a literal match, wrap the meta-characters in brackets. For example, '[?]' matches the character '?'.

```
pattern = "*[[]Ver.2]*"
```